# How to Start a "Session" on a MVC Project Using the Token Generated in a Seperate Web API Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization, token

I have two seperate projects in one solution. One is the Web Api and the other is MVC. The Web Api project doesn't have an interface. It has the Owin token generating mechanism. The MVC project has the views for user interface and the controllers for making Http Requests and receiving the responses.

On MVC project, I basicly send the username and password to the /token endpoint of the Web Api project using HttpClient. Then the Web Api project checks whether the credentials are matching the DB or not. And if it they are, it generates and returns the Access Token, Token Type, Expiration Date, the Refresh Token and Username values to the MVC project.

My question is, how can I use the token and other information that Web Api project returns to MVC project to start some kind of "session"? By session I mean, I want create a indicator on the MVC project that shows the user is logged in. That indicator should also be accessible on the view layer (to show the logged in username etc.). Also how should I store the Token and Username on MVC project and be able to post them in the requests to the Api project to access the endpoints that requires Authorization?

P.S. I prefer using HttpClient for the request and responses, not ajax nor any JS frameworks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Modal like below in MVC project :

```
class SessionValues
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

And Covert the Token API response in this modal object and Store this object in Session variable like

```
SessionValues tokenData=convert response from token endpoint to this entity
Session["TokenData"]=tokenData;
```

Now whenever u make an API call, Use the token value stored in Session["TokenData"] for authorization. Also, You can add a check on **ExpiryDate** property of this to check whether the token is expired or not and if required you can fetch the new token again.

Comment: Do sessions have a "check" mechanism to see whether the user logged in or not? Also how can I check if ExpiryDate is expired?

Comment: You can set values in session once the user is logged in and clear the session when user click on Logout option Also you have to manually add a check for ExpiryDate before making an API call. You have to compare current DateTime with expiry date for checking token validity.